# Extract consecutive array elements with non-zero value

Tags: java

i have trouble coming up with an algorithm that will extract the indices of elements that is found to have 5 or more consecutive **non-zero** values (of the element).

My current source can't handle some combination of the elements, and usually breaks when trying to do some combination tests. Currently, im at a lost as to the effecient algorithm to make.

Here is my code

***NOTE: this works like a charm, but i'm looking for the best way for this (both in Algorithm and Syntax in java, maybe using streams or something)***

```
    //determine the consecutive 1s on mapping 
    //reverse traverse
    for(int i = bitmap.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int current = bitmap[i];
        int next = 0;
        
        if (current != 0) {
            
            extractIndexes.add(i);  
            if ((i - 1) >= 0) {
                next = bitmap[i - 1];
                if (current == 0) {
                    extractIndexes.clear();
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Here is a sample input

[image]

in the above input, i want to extract the indexes `{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`

Is there a best way to go about this ?

Comment: So you want to extract only the indexes where you have **two or more** consecutive 1's (so exclude index 12  because it's on its own)? And also you want to extract them in reverse order (in other words you want `{8,7,6,5,4,3}`)?

Comment: actullay reverse order is not necessary, its just part of my algorithm to extract the indices. 
also, was not able to put the limit, consecutive should be 5 or more. I will update the description

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be fun to try it out, here is what I came up with

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1};
    String output = "";
    int consecutiveVal = 1;

    int consecutive = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if(i != 0){
            if(values[i] == values[i-1] && values[i] == consecutiveVal){
                if(consecutive == 0){
                    output += (i-1) + " ";
                }
                consecutive++;
            }
            else{
                consecutive = 0;
            }
        }
        if(consecutive >= 1){
            output += i + " ";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

I haven't done Java in a while, so I didn't get it to output into another array, but you should be able to figure that one out